# Every page returns an error on my Rails production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When using a production server started with `rails s -e production`, every page I visit returns this error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

I don't know what the error means, or even if it's the same type of error every time, although it's the same text every time.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

config/environments/production.rb:

```
Website::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

end
```

Comment: what do your logs in log/production.log say?

Comment: type `heroku logs -a yourappname` in terminal and look for the problem

Comment: So you know, the "We're sorry" message is the default `public/500.html` page. You are getting a 500 response from the server, which is an internal server error. One thing to think about: does your production database exist?

Comment: @hjing I don't have a production.log... is  that bad?

Comment: @ptd I never took any steps to create one. How do I check?

Comment: `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production` and `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Answer (score 0):

You're forgot to made some production usage preparations for Rails app.

1. Ensure the user that running your Rails application have permissions to write logs in `log` directory.
2. Ensure your secret key and rails env. Secret key used for cookies security. Tou just can create enviroment variable and Rails can retrive it `export SECRET_KEY_BASE=$(rake secret)` Rails env used to tell you Rails app running in production mode `export RAILS_ENV=production`
3. Ensure you DB if configured right. You need to create `config/database.yml` with your DB adapter configuration, after that run `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`.
4. Ensure your assets precompiled. Just run `rake assets:precompile`
5. After all of that you can run `rails s`

But this is not right way to run your Rails app in production. For nice and reliable production you're need to use Nginx as load-balancer and alternative application server such as Puma or Passenger.